# gnuplot connecting points of equal x values from two files

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I would like to create a plot from two files, but would like to connect lines of equal x values:

file1.txt

x         y

1.0      4.4

3.3      5.3

5.9      7.0

8.8      6.1

file2.txt

x     y

1.0  10.1

4.1  12.4

7.4  17.0

7.8  9.1

So I would like to plot the two files, but join lines of equal x values; i.e. for x = 1.0 there should be a line joining those two points. Any ideas how?

Comment: Hmm thats an unusual question. I'd be surprised if there is an easy solution. Because it is quite an undertaking to check which for each x-entry in one file if there is the similar one in the other, for large files. If the files aren't too big, I think you should do it manually by using `set arrow from x1,y1 to x1, y2 nohead`. Or you can prepare a  separate file with the correct points pairwise with a blank line between the pairs, and plot that file too. That might be easier and give the same result. May be awk can help you with that if you learn how.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you only want to connect points with equal values in the first column, and ignore all other points, then you can use the `vectors` plotting style and the command line utility `join` to combine your files:

```
plot '< join file1.txt file2.txt' using 1:2:(0):($3-$2) with vectors nohead
```

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that gnuplot's main focus is on plotting and not on data preparation. Therefore, just for fun and for the records...

- In case you are working under Linux, Christoph's solution is certainly the shortest and most efficient.
- If you are working under Windows, you first have to install comparable utilities, e.g. CoreUtils from [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)
- If you want a platform-independent *gnuplot-only* solution *without* extra installations, check the example below.

Basically, two gnuplot features are necessary:

1. plotting `with table` which you can use to remove `NaN`s and/or you can merge two datasets (however, only sequentially).
2. the plotting option `smooth freq` which you can use for sorting datafiles (however, only with two columns).

So, repeated merging and sorting will finally lead to the desired dataset for plotting. I don't want to say that this is efficient, but *platform-independent* and *gnuplot-only*.

**Assumption:** `$Data1` and `$Data2` only contain unique x-values.

A few explanations:

- `$Temp3b` column 1 will contain all unique x-values from `Data1` and `$Data2`. Column 2 will contain either `1`, `2` or `3`. The meaning of `1` or `2`: x-value occurs only in `$Data1` or `$Data2`, respectively.  `3`: x-value occurs in both datasets.
- `$Temp4b` column 1 contains all unique x-values. Column 2 contains all corresponding y-values from `$Data1` and `0` for those x-values which only occur in `$Data2`.
- `$Temp4d` column 1 contains all unique x-values. Column 2 contains all corresponding y-values from `$Data2`
  and `0` for those x-values which only occur in `$Data1`.
- `$Temp5a` append the x-values from `$Temp4b`, and the y-values from `$Temp4b`, `$Temp4d` and `$Temp3b` and adding the line index with a small offset.
- `$Temp5b` this offset can now be used to sort the lines of `$Temp5a`.
- `$Temp6a` checks if 4 consecutive lines belong to the same line index and if the one with offset `.4` equals `3`, i.e. x-value is occurring in both datasets `$Data1` and `$Data2`. If yes, plot the corresponding values into one line, otherwise add a line with `NaN`s.
- `$Data3` removes `NaN`s lines from `$Temp6a`.
- Finally, `plot $Data3 u 1:2:(0):(column(3)-column(2)) w vectors`

**Data:**

`SO32607004_1.dat`

```
1   0
2   1
3   6
4   2
6   3
8   5
9   8
```

`SO32607004_2.dat`

```
1   2
3   3
5   5
6   7
7   11
8   7
9   9
```

**Code 1:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0 version at the time of OP's question)

```
### connect points of equal x from two files (gnuplot>=5.0.0)
reset session

FILE1 = 'SO32607004_1.dat'
FILE2 = 'SO32607004_2.dat'

set table $Temp3a
    plot FILE1 u 1:(1) w table
    plot FILE2 u 1:(2) w table
set table $Temp3b
    plot $Temp3a u 1:2 smooth freq
set table $Temp4a
    plot FILE1 u 1:2   w table
    plot FILE2 u 1:(0) w table
set table $Temp4b
    plot $Temp4a u 1:2 smooth freq
set table $Temp4c
    plot FILE1 u 1:(0) w table
    plot FILE2 u 1:2 w table
set table $Temp4d
    plot $Temp4c u 1:2 smooth freq
set table $Temp5a
    plot $Temp4b u ($0+0.1):1 w table
    plot $Temp4b u ($0+0.2):2 w table
    plot $Temp4d u ($0+0.3):2 w table
    plot $Temp3b u ($0+0.4):2 w table
set table $Temp5b
    plot $Temp5a u 1:2 smooth freq
unset table

print "Temp3b:\n", $Temp3b
print "Temp4b:\n", $Temp4b
print "Temp4d:\n", $Temp4d
print "Temp5b:\n", $Temp5b

CheckX(col1,col2) = (x1=x2, x2=x3, x3=x4, x4=column(col1), \
                     y1=y2, y2=y3, y3=y4, y4=column(col2), \
                     (floor(x1)==floor(x4) && y4==3) ? 1 : 0)
     
set table $Temp6a
    plot x4=x3=x2=y4=y3=y2=NaN $Temp5b u ( (ok=CheckX(1,2)) ? y1 : NaN):(ok ? y2:NaN):(ok ? y3:NaN) w table
set table $Data3
    set datafile missing "NaN"
    plot $Temp6a u 1:2:3 w table
unset table
print "Data3:\n", $Data3

set offsets 1,1,1,1
set key top left

plot FILE1 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"  ti "FILE1", \
     FILE2 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti "FILE2", \
     $Data3 u 1:2:(0):(column(3)-column(2)) w vec lw 1.5 lc "web-green" ti "connect equal x-values"
### end of code
```

**Result 1:** `$Data3`

```
 1       0       2
 3       6       3
 6       3       7
 8       5       7
 9       8       9
```

**Code 2:** (shorter version for gnuplot>=5.2.0)

```
### connect points of equal x from two files (gnuplot>=5.2.0)
reset session

FILE1 = 'SO32607004_1.dat'
FILE2 = 'SO32607004_2.dat'

set table $Temp3a
    plot FILE1 u 1:(1) w table
    plot FILE2 u 1:(2) w table
set table $Temp3b
    plot $Temp3a u 1:2 smooth freq
set table $Temp4a
    plot FILE1 u 1:2   w table
    plot FILE2 u 1:(0) w table
set table $Temp4b
    plot $Temp4a u 1:2 smooth freq
set table $Temp4c
    plot FILE1 u 1:(0) w table
    plot FILE2 u 1:2 w table
set table $Temp4d
    plot $Temp4c u 1:2 smooth freq
unset table
set print $Data3
    do for [i=1:|$Temp3b|] {
        print sprintf("%s %s %s",$Temp3b[i], $Temp4b[i], $Temp4d[i])
    }
set print

set offsets 1,1,1,1
set key top left

plot FILE1  u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"  ti "$Data1", \
     FILE2  u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti "$Data2", \
     $Data3 u 4:($2==3?$5:NaN):(0):($8-$5) w vec lw 1.5 lc "web-green" ti "connect equal x-values"
### end of code
```

**Result 2:** `$Data3`

```
 1  3  i  1  0  i  1  2  i
 2  1  i  2  1  i  2  0  i
 3  3  i  3  6  i  3  3  i
 4  1  i  4  2  i  4  0  i
 5  2  i  5  0  i  5  5  i
 6  3  i  6  3  i  6  7  i
 7  2  i  7  0  i  7  11  i
 8  3  i  8  5  i  8  7  i
 9  3  i  9  8  i  9  9  i
```

**Result:** (graph for both codes)

[image]